# ZK set selected item after AnnotateDataBinder loadAll()

Tags: listbox, zk

I'm new to ZK. I have a Listbox with a List  as model. When I receive an update event I update the information in the model and then I update the UI using

```
AnnotateDataBinder binder = (AnnotateDataBinder) vesselsList.getPage().getAttribute("binder");
if (binder != null) {
      binder.loadAll();   
}
```

The problem is that after the update, in the following code

```
List updatedObjects = object.getItems();
for (Object obj : updatedObjects) {
Listitem data =  (Listitem) obj;              
Object ob =  data.getValue();
```

The data.getValue() is always null.
I have search the internet for many days and I found that the binder launches an onInitRenderLater event after load everything but I can't manage to make it work.

My intent is if I have an item selected before the update,I want it to remain selected and the binder.loadAll().

Answer (score 0):

Did you setValue to your items with annotated databinding ?

```
<listitem value="@{bean.data}" > ....  </listitem>
```

Comment: I had to make it onAfterCompose or the value was null.

Comment: any complete code ? or use zkfiddle.org to duplicate the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In zul I made

```
<listbox model="@{objects_model}" id="objectsList"
```

and in Java I call the method

```
public void onAfterRender$objectsList(Event event) {
    // select item here after the listbox has been rendered
}
```

it did the trick